# MS Access IIf Function

Tags: ms-access, syntax-error, iif

I have a calculated field on a table at MS Access and I'd like to use the following syntax, but it returns a syntax error pop-up and and I'm wondering which part is wrong. Could you please help with this? Thanks a lot.

IIf([Letter_Grade]="A+",4,IIf([Letter_Grade]="A",4,IIf([Letter_Grade]="A",3.7,IIf([Letter_Grade]="B+",3.3,IIf([Letter_Grade]="B",3,IIf([Letter_Grade]="B",2.7,IIf([Letter_Grade]="C+",2.3,IIf([Letter_Grade]="C",2,IIf([Letter_Grade]="C",1.7,IIf([Letter_Grade]="D+",1.3,IIf([Letter_Grade]="D",1,IIf([Letter_Grade]="D-",0.7,IIf([Letter_Grade]="F",0)))))))))))))

Comment: This is a nightmare... I suggest using a lookup table that translates grades to values.

Comment: What Andre said. A small VBA method with a large `Select Case` statement will be much more readable.

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions. I haven't used both (lookup table or VBA method) yet, but I'll definitely take a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding ",null" after your last expression:

```
IIf([Letter_Grade]="F",0,null)))))))))))))
```

Though it may be better to use a query?

Comment: Thank you very much for the correction. I tired it and it worked! I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

The function works well, did you put = operator before it.

Attached are some images of the results I got and the function

[image: Design view]

[image: B+]

[image: A+]

[image: A-]

[image: A]

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment and pictures. I tried with = operator before the expression but still returns the same error. What I did was, 1. Open Expression Builder 2. Copy & Paste the expression 3. Click OK. Then, I see the expression in General tab expression properties. However, when I save the table, it returns, "Syntax Error in Expression" (click OK) and then "Errors were encountered during the save operation. Fields were not added. Properties were not updated". I'm a newbie to MS Access. Could you find some problems that I did? Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you adding it to a form or a table?  It should be added to a form.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was working on a table.